# How is this statement making sense? (Sun's naming convention for Java variables)

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I've been quoting this segment from Sun's document for the past few days, and only now do I stop and think about what it's saying, and I can't make any sense of it. Please keep in mind that English is not my first language.

#### [Naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html)

> Variables: Except for variables, all instance, class, and class constants are in mixed case with a *lowercase first letter*.

How is this making sense? Isn't this saying that class names are in mixed case with a lower-case first letter? Like I should name it `class myClass`? And class constants are also in mixed case with a lower-case first letter? Like instead of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, it should've been named `integer.maxValue`?

And is it really saying anything about how variables themselves should be named?

Am I not parsing this properly or is this actually a blatant error?

Comment: Seems like out of context or badly edited...

Comment: Seems like a typo to me.

Comment: @Gabriel: that link is clickable to Sun's own official website. You can see the whole context and tell me if it makes sense.

Comment: I looked at archive.org this texts dates to Feb 15, 1998, so I could not find any explanation. Maybe they wanted to write "including" and omit extra "class"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sun has accepted this as a **bug**, with low priority:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4311597

> describing the convention for naming variables (the penultimate row in the table).  It is plainly wrong - class
> constants are not in mixed case, as the next row in the table shows.  And what is this "except for variables"
> business?  The text is *supposed* to be describing variables!!

> The text should read:

> "All instance and class variables are in mixed..."

> thus dropping the words "except for variables" and "class constants"

Comment: Awesome. Finally a definitive admittance that it's a mistake, and I've not gone crazy and forgotten how to parse English. Well, I may still be going crazy nonetheless.

Comment: Well, it says low priority, I guess they mean it... +1 the bug until it is fixed, it only has one vote...

Comment: @Stephen - Done. It seems I even had an account. Amazing.

Answer (score 3):

This is a few boxes above it:

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple and descriptive. Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form, such as URL or HTML).

```
class Raster;
class ImageSprite;
```

and below that:

> The names of variables declared class constants and of ANSI constants should be all uppercase with words separated by underscores ("_"). (ANSI constants should be avoided, for ease of debugging.)

```
static final int MIN_WIDTH = 4;

static final int MAX_WIDTH = 999;

static final int GET_THE_CPU = 1;
```

Contradicting, no? "Class constants" should be **excluded** from that variables convention statement, even if they mean non-static constants of the `public final` kind, as it confuses people.

As for "except for variables," I believe they mean primitive [local variables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) should only be one word.

Comment: The question is not what the other boxes are saying. The question is what is this box saying. Because it doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: The best way to get around this is to look at the context.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly a badly-edited version of what is actually meant:

> Variables: All variables names
>   (excluding constants) are in mixed
>   case with a lowercase first letter.

Comment: Yes, that would've made sense, as that _should_ be the official recommendation. I'm just surprised that this presumably official document contained such a glaring error and it's uncaught after all this time.

Comment: The statement as written makes no sense.  I stared at it for a while with a funny look on my face, trying to make sense of it.  But in hundreds of pages of recommendations, these things get missed.

Comment: So how am I suppose to quote the authority on this recommendation in my answers? I always fall back on this quote whenever I see people name their variables with uppercase first letter; only now do I realize that it's not making any sense, and is probably making things worse for them.

Comment: The text you're referencing is clearly nonsensical.  Contact Oracle, ask for a fix.  Refer to other coding convention sites, like http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html: "Variable names must be in mixed case starting with lower case."

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the whole thing to get the context:

> Except for variables, all instance,
>   class, and class constants are in
>   mixed case with a lowercase first
>   letter. Internal words start with
>   capital letters. Variable names should
>   not start with underscore _ or dollar
>   sign $ characters, even though both
>   are allowed.
>
> Variable names should be short yet
>   meaningful. The choice of a variable
>   name should be mnemonic- that is,
>   designed to indicate to the casual
>   observer the intent of its use.
>   One-character variable names should be
>   avoided except for temporary
>   "throwaway" variables. Common names
>   for temporary variables are i, j, k,
>   m, and n for integers; c, d, and e for
>   characters.

So [local] variables are to be short (meaning they may not have enough "words" to have mixed case).

All other variables (those at the instance or class level, the non-local ones) are to be have mixed case and start with a lower case letter (and presumably be "wordy" enough to be able to have mixed case, like "lineNumber" instead of "number");

EDIT (forgot about constants).

There are two ways of looking at constants in Java:

1. anything with the word final
2. anything with a guaranteed value
   that is always the same

so:

```
class Foo
{
    public final int variable;
    public final int CONSTANT;

    static
    {
        variable = // generate a random number.
        CONSTANT = 5;
    }
}
```

Here "variable" is "constant" in that once it is assigned a value it cannot change, but it is not a constant like "CONSTANT" since "CONSTANT" will always have a value of 5.

I consider #2 to be the only constants in Java.

EDIT #2 (in response to the comment below).

I would re-write that as:

> Except for local variables, all
>   instance, class, and class blank
>   finals [and I might also specify that
>   the blank final be without have a
>   single compile time value] are in
>   mixed case with a lowercase first
>   letter.

You can look at http://www.codeguru.com/java/tij/tij0071.shtml for some more of a description.

Comment: That first sentence still doesn't make any sense to me, and at least a few others ("Except" being an important keyword). If it makes sense to you, you need to explain it better to us.