# VBA array slices (not in the Pythonic sense)

Tags: arrays, vba

**How should I implement this function?**

```
Public Function ArraySlice(arr As Variant, dimension as Long, index as Long) As Variant

    'Implementation here

End Function
```

Suppose I wanted a slice of an array. I specify an array, a dimension and an index on that dimension for which I want the slice.

As a concrete example, suppose I have the following 5x4 2D array

```
   0  1  2  3  4
  ______________
0| 1  1  2  3  1
1| 3  4  2  1  5
2| 4  5  3  2  6
3| 3  5  2  1  3
```

If the horizontal dimension is 1 and the vertical is 2, the return value of `ArraySlice(array, 1, 3)` would be a 1x4 2D array. The chosen dimension 2 was flattened and the only remaining values are the ones that were originally at index 3 on dimension 2:

```
   0
  ____
0| 3
1| 1
2| 2
3| 1
```

How would you implement this in VBA? The only implementations I can think of would involve CopyMemory unless I limited the number of dimensions allowable and hard coded every case.

*NOTE: [Here is how I would get the dimensions of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26555865/2832561)*

**UPDATE**

Here are a couple more examples of the operation

For the 2D array

```
   0  1  2  3  4
  ______________
0| 1  1  2  3  1
1| 3  4  2  1  5
2| 4  5  3  2  6
3| 3  5  2  1  3
```

The result of `ArraySlice(array, 2, 2)` would be

```
   0  1  2  3  4
  ______________
0| 4  5  3  2  6
```

Suppose I had a 3x3x3 array comprised of the following 2 dimensional slices
*this example has been changed to make it clearer*

```
     0  1  2        0  1  2         0  1  2
0   _________   1   _________  2   _________
  0| 1  1  1      0| 4  4  4     0| 7  7  7
  1| 2  2  2      1| 5  5  5     1| 8  8  8 
  2| 3  3  3      2| 6  6  6     2| 9  9  9
```

(constructed like so)

```
Dim arr() As Long

ReDim arr(2, 2, 2)

arr(0, 0, 0) = 1
arr(1, 0, 0) = 1
arr(2, 0, 0) = 1
arr(0, 1, 0) = 2
arr(1, 1, 0) = 2
arr(2, 1, 0) = 2
arr(0, 2, 0) = 3
arr(1, 2, 0) = 3
arr(2, 2, 0) = 3
arr(0, 0, 1) = 4
arr(1, 0, 1) = 4
arr(2, 0, 1) = 4
arr(0, 1, 1) = 5
arr(1, 1, 1) = 5
arr(2, 1, 1) = 5
arr(0, 2, 1) = 6
arr(1, 2, 1) = 6
arr(2, 2, 1) = 6
arr(0, 0, 2) = 7
arr(1, 0, 2) = 7
arr(2, 0, 2) = 7
arr(0, 1, 2) = 8
arr(1, 1, 2) = 8
arr(2, 1, 2) = 8
arr(0, 2, 2) = 9
arr(1, 2, 2) = 9
arr(2, 2, 2) = 9
```

(the dimensions are used in the mathematical x, y, z sense as opposed to the rows/cols sense)

The result of `ArraySlice(array, 3, 1)` would be the 3x3x1 array

```
     0  1  2
0   _________
  0| 4  4  4  
  1| 5  5  5  
  2| 6  6  6
```

The result of `ArraySlice(array, 2, 2)` would be the 3x1x3 array

```
     0  1  2        0  1  2         0  1  2
0   _________   1   _________  2   _________
  0| 3  3  3      0| 6  6  6     0| 9  9  9
```

**UPDATE2**

For DavidZemens, here is an example that would allow easier tracking of the elements involved:

For a 3x3x3 array constructed like so

```
Dim arr() As Long

ReDim arr(2, 2, 2)

arr(0, 0, 0) = "000"
arr(1, 0, 0) = "100"
arr(2, 0, 0) = "200"
arr(0, 1, 0) = "010"
arr(1, 1, 0) = "110"
arr(2, 1, 0) = "210"
arr(0, 2, 0) = "020"
arr(1, 2, 0) = "120"
arr(2, 2, 0) = "220"
arr(0, 0, 1) = "001"
arr(1, 0, 1) = "101"
arr(2, 0, 1) = "201"
arr(0, 1, 1) = "011"
arr(1, 1, 1) = "111"
arr(2, 1, 1) = "211"
arr(0, 2, 1) = "021"
arr(1, 2, 1) = "121"
arr(2, 2, 1) = "221"
arr(0, 0, 2) = "001"
arr(1, 0, 2) = "102"
arr(2, 0, 2) = "202"
arr(0, 1, 2) = "012"
arr(1, 1, 2) = "112"
arr(2, 1, 2) = "212"
arr(0, 2, 2) = "022"
arr(1, 2, 2) = "122"
arr(2, 2, 2) = "222"
```

The result of `ArraySlice(array, 3, 1)` would be the 3x3x1 array

```
       0     1     2
0   ___________________
  0| "001" "101" "201"  
  1| "011" "111" "211"
  2| "021" "121" "221"
```

**FINAL UPDATE**

Here is the complete solution - you can assume that the Array functions are implemented as @GSerg suggests in the accepted answer. I decided that it makes more sense to completely flatten the sliced dimension, so if a slice of a 3x3x3 array ("cube") is 3x1x3, it gets flattened to 3x3. I still have to resolve the case where flattening a 1 dimensional array would yield a 0 dimensional array by this method.

```
Public Function ArraySlice(arr As Variant, dimension As Long, index As Long) As Variant

    'TODO: Assert that arr is an Array
    'TODO: Assert dimension is valid
    'TODO: Assert index is valid

    Dim arrDims As Integer
    arrDims = GetArrayDim(arr) 'N dimensions
    Dim arrType As Integer
    arrType = GetArrayType(arr)

    Dim zeroIndexedDimension As Integer
    zeroIndexedDimension = dimension - 1 'Make the dimension zero indexed by subtracting one, for easier math


    Dim newArrDims As Integer
    newArrDims = arrDims - 1 'N-1 dimensions since we're flattening "dimension" on "index"

    Dim arrDimSizes() As Variant
    Dim newArrDimSizes() As Variant

    ReDim arrDimSizes(0 To arrDims - 1)
    ReDim newArrDimSizes(0 To newArrDims - 1)

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To arrDims - 1
        arrDimSizes(i) = UBound(arr, i + 1) - LBound(arr, i + 1) + 1
    Next

    'Get the size of each corresponding dimension of the original
    For i = 0 To zeroIndexedDimension - 1
        newArrDimSizes(i) = arrDimSizes(i)
    Next

    'Skip over "dimension" since we're flattening it

    'Get the remaining dimensions, off by one
    For i = zeroIndexedDimension To arrDims - 2
        newArrDimSizes(i) = arrDimSizes(i + 1)
    Next

    Dim newArray As Variant
    newArray = CreateArray(arrType, newArrDims, newArrDimSizes)


    'Iterate through dimensions, copying

    Dim arrCurIndices() As Variant
    Dim newArrCurIndices() As Variant

    ReDim arrCurIndices(0 To arrDims - 1)
    ReDim newArrCurIndices(0 To newArrDims - 1)

    arrCurIndices(zeroIndexedDimension) = index 'This is the slice

    Do While 1

        'Copy the element
        PutArrayElement newArray, GetArrayElement(arr, arrCurIndices), newArrCurIndices

        'Iterate both arrays to the next position
        If Not IncrementIndices(arrCurIndices, arrDimSizes, zeroIndexedDimension) Then
            'If we've copied all the elements
            Exit Do
        End If
        IncrementIndices newArrCurIndices, newArrDimSizes
    Loop

    ArraySlice = newArray
End Function

Private Function IncrementIndices(arrIndices As Variant, arrDimensionSizes As Variant, Optional zeroIndexedDimension As Integer = -2) As Boolean
    'IncrementArray iterates sequentially through all valid indices, given the sizes in arrDimensionSizes
    'For example, suppose the function is called repeatedly with starting arrIndices of [0, 0, 0] and arrDimensionSizes of [3, 1, 3].
    'The result would be arrIndices changing as follows:
    '[0, 0, 0] first call
    '[0, 0, 1]
    '[0, 0, 2]
    '[1, 0, 0]
    '[1, 0, 1]
    '[1, 0, 2]
    '[2, 0, 0]
    '[2, 0, 1]
    '[2, 0, 2]

    'The optional "dimension" parameter allows a dimension to be frozen and not included in the iteration.
    'For example, suppose the function is called repeatedly with starting arrIndices of [0, 1, 0] and arrDimensionSizes of [3, 3, 3] and dimension = 2
    '[0, 1, 0] first call
    '[0, 1, 1]
    '[0, 1, 2]
    '[1, 1, 0]
    '[1, 1, 1]
    '[1, 1, 2]
    '[2, 1, 0]
    '[2, 1, 1]
    '[2, 1, 2]


    Dim arrCurDimension As Integer
    arrCurDimension = UBound(arrIndices)

    'If this dimension is "full" or if it is the frozen dimension, skip over it looking for a carry
    While arrIndices(arrCurDimension) = arrDimensionSizes(arrCurDimension) - 1 Or arrCurDimension = zeroIndexedDimension
        'Carry
        arrCurDimension = arrCurDimension - 1

        If arrCurDimension = -1 Then
            IncrementIndices = False
            Exit Function
        End If

    Wend
    arrIndices(arrCurDimension) = arrIndices(arrCurDimension) + 1
    While arrCurDimension < UBound(arrDimensionSizes)
        arrCurDimension = arrCurDimension + 1
        If arrCurDimension <> zeroIndexedDimension Then
            arrIndices(arrCurDimension) = 0
        End If
    Wend
    IncrementIndices = True
End Function
```

Comment: I chose to number the dimensions 1 and 2 because a null array could be considered to have 0 dimensions and I wouldn't want that to be confusing for myself later.

Comment: I fail to see how you could avoid copying "everything except" manually. You can create an array that [points the original array's data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11713408/11683), but that works because the data remains continuous. In your case it's not.

Comment: @GSerg Agreed, there is definitely not a way of doing it without copying. What I meant was the CopyMemory Win32 API function - I'm not sure if there is a way of writing the function using only built-in VBA array manipulations.

Comment: Not sure I understand the specific problem, but have you tried any of the helper functions that Ron de Bruin has posted? Specifically there is one that tests the number of dimensions in an array, and another which tests whether an array is truly "allocated", etc.

Comment: @DavidZemens I added a few more examples and cleared up some of my bad terminology - see if it makes more sense.

Comment: For the 2-d array it's pretty simple. Can you show a screenshot of what your 3d array looks like in the Locals window?

Comment: @DavidZemens I'll do you one better and give you code that builds it so you can play with it yourself!

Comment: I can imagine writing this function to handle just 2d arrays or just 3d arrays, but generalizing it to handle any number (to the limit imposed by VBA) of finite dimensions is what really bakes my noodle.

Comment: Since `VBA` does not have `Rank()` function like `VB.NET` I doubt you can use the same function for 2D, 3D, xD arrays. You will need to make separate functions like `ArraySlice2` and `ArraySlice3`. Also VBA does not have buffered copy so you will need to copy one by one the elements. Only if you can squeeze a `Redim Preserve arr(...)` statement in there you might save some time.

Comment: @ja72 See the link I provided for a "Rank()" function - I called it `GetDims`, but it does basically what you're talking about.

Comment: Right @ja72 -- there's just not a good built-in way to iterate over the dimensions in the array, the iteration loops would need to be dynamically built based on the number of dimensions in the array.  I would probably use some other data structure (Collection or Dictionary) and try to limit myself to manageable, expected cases (2- or 3-levels of nesting).

Comment: @DavidZemens If I have that 3x3x3 array and I do `ArraySlice(array, 3, 1)`, I get a 3x3x1 array (you can think of it as a square whose edges are along the X and Y dimensions - a square "standing on edge facing you") with the values of index 1 in the 3rd dimension.  With the same 3x3x3 array, if I do `ArraySlice(array, 2, 1)` I would get a 3x1x3 array (a square with the edges along the X and Z dimensions - a square lying "flat on the floor") with the values of index 1 in the 2nd dimension.

Comment: The dimensions would be like a coordinate system flat on a wall in front of you. X is positive to the right and negative left. Y is positive down and negative upwards. Z is positive towards you and negative away from you. This is kind of relative - it doesn't matter which way you interpret the dimensions so long as it's consistent.

Comment: Do you really need to handle an unknown number of dimensions? And does the array at each dimension also need to account for unknown number of dimensions? Like, might you have to deal with an array like `Dim arr(5, 6, 3, 1 to 9)`  What I'm getting at is that if you have some known constraints, this "problem" should be manageable, although there isn't an *easy* way to do it.  If you literally have to account for every possible combination, I think you're boned.

Comment: @DavidZemens Technically, no, I don't need an unknown number of dimensions. The problem I originally encountered required two, but when possible and reasonable I like to generalize. When I realized generalization wasn't trivial, I decided to post this question to see if someone else could see something I missed. Incidentally I should note that I appreciate all your time and effort! (also, for the sake of my sanity I only use 0 based array indices)

Comment: You can completely flatten the array in to an ArrayList, and then use some fancy modular iteration based on the number of dimensions, etc., probably. But I'm not sure if that would be any better than brute force nested loops, and my Excel just crapped out on me without the "recovery" panel, so I lost my tinkerings....

Comment: @DavidZemens I'm going to put a bounty on the question as soon as SO lets me - I'd be very interested to see any ideas you have!

Comment: There's some weird symmetry to the example data I don't know if that was on purpose but it's making it more confusing than need be...

Comment: @DavidZemens yeah... that has more to do with my laziness and the proximity of the keys on the keyboard than anything practical or necessary.  I could just as easily change the example to have the first slice be all 1's, the second all 2's and the third all 3's if that would help.

Comment: no, that would be even less helpful. when trying to step through this I need to be able to *see* that the right elements are being selected, etc.  I made a revision to use some string values, not sure if it needs further "approval" though but I gave values like `arr(0,0,0) = "000"`, etc., so that the value corresponds to its XYZ coordinate.

Comment: Could you update to show the expected return from the `ArraySlice(array, 3, 1)`  based on the string values in the array?

Comment: I think the only possible way to slice an array with an arbitrary number of dimensions is through recursion, although we can quickly run out of stack memory for large dimensions

Comment: @Jeanno Actually, the method that GSerg suggests is sufficient. I'm about 90% done with it, and once I do I'll post back in an update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Note:** the code has been updated, the original version can be found in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32539884/revisions) (not that it is useful to find it). The updated code does not depend on the undocumented `GetMem*` functions and is compatible with Office 64-bit.

I'm not sure I fully understand the logic and the connection between the function arguments and the result, but there already is a generic element accessor function, `SafeArrayGetElement`. It lets you access an element of an array with dimensions unknown at compile time, all you need is the [array pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183353/11683).

In a separate module:

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
  Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal length As LongPtr)
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function SafeArrayGetElement Lib "oleaut32.dll" (ByVal psa As LongPtr, ByRef rgIndices As Long, ByRef pv As Any) As Long
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function SafeArrayGetVartype Lib "oleaut32.dll" (ByVal psa As LongPtr, ByRef pvt As Integer) As Long
#Else
  Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal length As Long)
  Private Declare Function SafeArrayGetElement Lib "oleaut32.dll" (ByVal psa As Long, ByRef rgIndices As Long, ByRef pv As Any) As Long
  Private Declare Function SafeArrayGetVartype Lib "oleaut32.dll" (ByVal psa As Long, ByRef pvt As Integer) As Long
#End If

Private Const VT_BYREF As Long = &H4000&
Private Const S_OK As Long = &H0&

' When declared in this way, the passed array is wrapped in a Variant/ByRef. It is not copied.
' Returns *SAFEARRAY, not **SAFEARRAY
#If VBA7 Then
Private Function pArrPtr(ByRef arr As Variant) As LongPtr
#Else
Private Function pArrPtr(ByRef arr As Variant) As Long
#End If
  'VarType lies to you, hiding important differences. Manual VarType here.
  Dim vt As Integer
  CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(vt), ByVal VarPtr(arr), Len(vt)

  If (vt And vbArray) <> vbArray Then
    Err.Raise 5, , "Variant must contain an array"
  End If

  'see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
  If (vt And VT_BYREF) = VT_BYREF Then
    'By-ref variant array. Contains **pparray at offset 8
    CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(pArrPtr), ByVal VarPtr(arr) + 8, Len(pArrPtr)  'pArrPtr = arr->pparray;
    CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(pArrPtr), ByVal pArrPtr, Len(pArrPtr)          'pArrPtr = *pArrPtr;
  Else
    'Non-by-ref variant array. Contains *parray at offset 8
    CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(pArrPtr), ByVal VarPtr(arr) + 8, Len(pArrPtr)  'pArrPtr = arr->parray;
  End If
End Function


Public Function GetArrayElement(ByRef arr As Variant, ParamArray indices() As Variant) As Variant

#If VBA7 Then
  Dim pSafeArray As LongPtr
#Else
  Dim pSafeArray As Long
#End If

  pSafeArray = pArrPtr(arr)

  Dim long_indices() As Long
  ReDim long_indices(0 To UBound(indices) - LBound(indices))

  Dim i As Long
  For i = LBound(long_indices) To UBound(long_indices)
    long_indices(i) = indices(LBound(indices) + i)
  Next


  'Type safety checks - remove/cache if you know what you're doing.
  Dim hresult As Long

  Dim vt As Integer
  hresult = SafeArrayGetVartype(pSafeArray, vt)

  If hresult <> S_OK Then Err.Raise hresult, , "Cannot get array var type."


  Select Case vt
  Case vbVariant
    hresult = SafeArrayGetElement(ByVal pSafeArray, long_indices(LBound(long_indices)), GetArrayElement)
  Case vbBoolean, vbCurrency, vbDate, vbDecimal, vbByte, vbInteger, vbLong, vbNull, vbEmpty, vbSingle, vbDouble, vbString, vbObject
    hresult = SafeArrayGetElement(ByVal pSafeArray, long_indices(LBound(long_indices)), ByVal VarPtr(GetArrayElement) + 8)
    If hresult = S_OK Then CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(GetArrayElement), ByVal VarPtr(vt), Len(vt)
  Case Else
    Err.Raise 5, , "Unsupported array element type"
  End Select

  If hresult <> S_OK Then Err.Raise hresult, , "Cannot get array element."
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim arrVariantByRef() As Variant
  ReDim arrVariantByRef(1 To 2, 1 To 3)

  Dim arrVariantNonByRef As Variant
  ReDim arrVariantNonByRef(1 To 2, 1 To 3)

  Dim arrOfLongs() As Long
  ReDim arrOfLongs(1 To 2, 1 To 3)

  Dim arrOfStrings() As String
  ReDim arrOfStrings(1 To 2, 1 To 3)

  Dim arrOfObjects() As Object
  ReDim arrOfObjects(1 To 2, 1 To 3)

  Dim arrOfDates() As Date
  ReDim arrOfDates(1 To 2, 1 To 3)

  arrVariantByRef(2, 3) = 42
  arrVariantNonByRef(2, 3) = 42
  arrOfLongs(2, 3) = 42
  arrOfStrings(2, 3) = "42!"
  Set arrOfObjects(2, 3) = Me
  arrOfDates(2, 3) = Now

  MsgBox GetArrayElement(arrVariantByRef, 2, 3)
  MsgBox GetArrayElement(arrVariantNonByRef, 2, 3)
  MsgBox GetArrayElement(arrOfLongs, 2, 3)
  MsgBox GetArrayElement(arrOfStrings, 2, 3)
  MsgBox GetArrayElement(arrOfObjects, 2, 3).Caption
  MsgBox GetArrayElement(arrOfDates, 2, 3)

End Sub
```

I believe you can easily build your logic using this base block, although it might be slower than you want.
There are some type checks in the code which you can remove - then it will be faster, but you will have to make sure you only pass arrays of correct underlying type. You can also cache the `pArray` and make `GetArrayElement` accept that instead of a raw array.

Comment: Now that I wrote all this, I'm thinking whether it is actually a bad thing to hardcode all 60 cases (there can be at most 60 dimensions in a VBA array)? You'd end up with a big `select case num` where each line accesses the array with increased number of dimensions. Realistically you're not even going to use 60 dimensions because it's an instant Out of Memory even if all sixty are as small as (0 to 1).

Comment: YESSSSS! This is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for! As for the problem I am trying to solve, imagine a cube of nine children's building blocks. You could take "slices" of that cube: the top 9 blocks, or the bottom or the middle; likewise you could instead take the nine blocks that form the left face or the right face, or the back face or the front face as a slice. That's what my question is about except in any number of dimensions. In a 2d 3x3 array, a slice would either be 3x1 or 1x3 depending upon which dimension you slice.

Comment: I went with `SafeArrayCreate()` for dynamic array creation, and I'm returning it as a Variant, so that part is good. I looked up the COM Automation documentation and it appears that only full on Objects get Reference Counts, so the Variant/Array destruction gets handled correctly by VBA. I'm currently trying to adapt the put/get functions.

Comment: One note, per the MSDN [SafeArrayGetElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221255(v=vs.85).aspx) page, "A vector of indexes for each dimension of the array. The right-most (least significant) dimension is rgIndices[0]. The left-most dimension is stored at rgIndices[psa->cDims – 1]. " Does that mean I'd have to reverse the order when copying from `indices()` to `long_indices()`?

Comment: @Blackhawk That's what I thought too and reversed them, and it did not work. Then I stopped reversing them and it worked.

Comment: I haven't fully finished the implementation of `ArraySlice`, but `PutArrayElement`, `GetArrayElement`, `CreateArray` are done. One thing I did change in `GetArrayElement` was adding ParamArray unpacking - sometimes it's convenient or even necessary to simply provide a single array instead of multiple parameters, so there is a check to see if `indices(0)` is an array, and if so to use that directly. I have all the pieces I need to build ArraySlice and I will post it back as an update to the question. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

My complete code is below, arr input is 1, 2 or 3 dimension array, 1 dimension array will return false.

```
Public Function ArraySlice(arr As Variant, dimension As Long, index As Long) As Variant
Dim arrDimension() As Byte
Dim retArray()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim arrSize As Long

' Get array dimension and size
On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To 3
    arrSize = 0
    arrSize = CInt(UBound(arr, i))
    If arrSize <> 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve arrDimension(i)
        arrDimension(i) = UBound(arr, i)
    End If
Next i
On Error GoTo 0

Select Case UBound(arrDimension)
Case 2
    If dimension = 1 Then
        ReDim retArray(arrDimension(2))
        For i = 0 To arrDimension(2)
            retArray(i) = arr(index, i)
        Next i
    ElseIf dimension = 2 Then
        ReDim retArray(arrDimension(1))
        For i = 0 To arrDimension(1)
            retArray(i) = arr(i, index)
        Next i
    End If

Case 3
    If dimension = 1 Then
        ReDim retArray(0, arrDimension(2), arrDimension(3))
        For j = 0 To arrDimension(3)
            For i = 0 To arrDimension(2)
                retArray(0, i, j) = arr(index, i, j)
            Next i
        Next j
    ElseIf dimension = 2 Then
        ReDim retArray(arrDimension(1), 0, arrDimension(3))
        For j = 0 To arrDimension(3)
            For i = 0 To arrDimension(1)
                retArray(i, 0, j) = arr(i, index, j)
            Next i
        Next j
    ElseIf dimension = 3 Then
        ReDim retArray(arrDimension(1), arrDimension(2), 0)
        For j = 0 To arrDimension(2)
            For i = 0 To arrDimension(1)
                retArray(i, j, 0) = arr(i, j, index)
            Next i
        Next j
    End If

Case Else
    ArraySlice = False
    Exit Function

End Select

ArraySlice = retArray
End Function
```

Simply test by the code below

```
Sub test()
Dim arr2D()
Dim arr3D()
Dim ret

ReDim arr2D(4, 3)
arr2D(0, 0) = 1
arr2D(1, 0) = 1
arr2D(2, 0) = 2
arr2D(3, 0) = 3
arr2D(4, 0) = 1
arr2D(0, 1) = 3
arr2D(1, 1) = 4
arr2D(2, 1) = 2
arr2D(3, 1) = 1
arr2D(4, 1) = 5
arr2D(0, 2) = 4
arr2D(1, 2) = 5
arr2D(2, 2) = 3
arr2D(3, 2) = 2
arr2D(4, 2) = 6
arr2D(0, 3) = 3
arr2D(1, 3) = 5
arr2D(2, 3) = 2
arr2D(3, 3) = 1
arr2D(4, 3) = 3

ReDim arr3D(2, 2, 2)
arr3D(0, 0, 0) = 1
arr3D(1, 0, 0) = 1
arr3D(2, 0, 0) = 1
arr3D(0, 1, 0) = 2
arr3D(1, 1, 0) = 2
arr3D(2, 1, 0) = 2
arr3D(0, 2, 0) = 3
arr3D(1, 2, 0) = 3
arr3D(2, 2, 0) = 3
arr3D(0, 0, 1) = 4
arr3D(1, 0, 1) = 4
arr3D(2, 0, 1) = 4
arr3D(0, 1, 1) = 5
arr3D(1, 1, 1) = 5
arr3D(2, 1, 1) = 5
arr3D(0, 2, 1) = 6
arr3D(1, 2, 1) = 6
arr3D(2, 2, 1) = 6
arr3D(0, 0, 2) = 7
arr3D(1, 0, 2) = 7
arr3D(2, 0, 2) = 7
arr3D(0, 1, 2) = 8
arr3D(1, 1, 2) = 8
arr3D(2, 1, 2) = 8
arr3D(0, 2, 2) = 9
arr3D(1, 2, 2) = 9
arr3D(2, 2, 2) = 9

ReDim arr3D(2, 2, 2)
arr3D(0, 0, 0) = "000"
arr3D(1, 0, 0) = "100"
arr3D(2, 0, 0) = "200"
arr3D(0, 1, 0) = "010"
arr3D(1, 1, 0) = "110"
arr3D(2, 1, 0) = "210"
arr3D(0, 2, 0) = "020"
arr3D(1, 2, 0) = "120"
arr3D(2, 2, 0) = "220"
arr3D(0, 0, 1) = "001"
arr3D(1, 0, 1) = "101"
arr3D(2, 0, 1) = "201"
arr3D(0, 1, 1) = "011"
arr3D(1, 1, 1) = "111"
arr3D(2, 1, 1) = "211"
arr3D(0, 2, 1) = "021"
arr3D(1, 2, 1) = "121"
arr3D(2, 2, 1) = "221"
arr3D(0, 0, 2) = "001"
arr3D(1, 0, 2) = "102"
arr3D(2, 0, 2) = "202"
arr3D(0, 1, 2) = "012"
arr3D(1, 1, 2) = "112"
arr3D(2, 1, 2) = "212"
arr3D(0, 2, 2) = "022"
arr3D(1, 2, 2) = "122"
arr3D(2, 2, 2) = "222"

' Here is function call
ret = ArraySlice(arr3D, 3, 1)
End If
```

Comment: I appreciate the amount of effort you've put in, but do you think you could find a way of generalizing it? I'm specifically looking for method that extends to any number of dimensions without hand coding.

Comment: OK, I will try later.

Comment: Can you give me an example for 4D and more dimension?

Comment: So you're going to have all cases hardcoded @AdisakAnusornsrirung - but the OP [does not want that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488012/vba-array-slices-not-in-the-pythonic-sense/32539884#comment52986897_32540681).

Comment: My function return array not single number. Except you input 1 array in parameter arr.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I wrote [all this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32539884/11683) and realized that you will need a similar element setter (based on [`SafeArrayPutElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `SafeArrayGetElement`) and a generic [array creation routine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11713643/11683), I'm thinking whether it is actually a bad thing to hardcode all 60 cases.

The reason is that there can be at most 60 dimensions in a VBA array, and 60 cases are not difficult to hardcode

I did not even type this code in, I used some Excel formulas to generate it:

```
Public Function GetArrayElement(ByRef arr As Variant, ParamArray indices()) As Variant
  Dim count As Long, lb As Long

  lb = LBound(indices)
  count = UBound(indices) - lb + 1

  Select Case count
  Case 1: GetArrayElement = arr(indices(lb))
  Case 2: GetArrayElement = arr(indices(lb), indices(lb + 1))
    ....
  Case Else
    Err.Raise 5, , "There can be no more than 60 dimensions"
  End Select

End Function

Public Sub SetArrayElement(ByRef arr As Variant, ByRef value As Variant, ParamArray indices())
  Dim count As Long, lb As Long

  lb = LBound(indices)
  count = UBound(indices) - lb + 1

  Select Case count
  Case 1: arr(indices(lb)) = value
  Case 2: arr(indices(lb), indices(lb + 1)) = value
    ....
  Case Else
    Err.Raise 5, , "There can be no more than 60 dimensions"
  End Select
End Sub
```

Unfortunately it's about twice longer than it is allowed in a post, so there is a link to full version: http://pastebin.com/KVqV3vyU

Comment: I think I will still try and avoid 60 hand coded cases if at all possible :P I had completely forgotten about the oleaut32 SafeArray functions - I'm playing around with SafeArrayCreateEx to find out if the memory management would prevent me from creating an array on the fly, returning it in a Variant and then using the functions you provided in your other answer.