# How to check if variable was declared as a Variant type

Tags: vba

Is there any way to check if variable was originally declared as `Variant` data type?

Consider the following example:

```
Public Sub mainMethod()
    Dim a As Variant
    Dim b As String

    a = "a"
    b = "b"

    Debug.Print "a: " & VBA.TypeName(a) & " | " & VBA.VarType(a)
    Debug.Print "b: " & VBA.TypeName(b) & " | " & VBA.VarType(b)

End Sub
```

Output is:

```
a: String | 8
b: String | 8
```

After assigning a text to the variable declared as `Variant`, both VBA built-in functions to check the type of variable (`VarType` and `TypeName`) treats it as variable of `String` type.

The effect is that variables `a` and `b` are treated the same way by those functions mentioned above, although originally they were declared with different data types.

I know how to check it by parsing method body with `VBE` functions, but it is not acceptable in this case.

Comment: The locals window will show you

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33941363/determining-the-full-type-of-a-variable

Comment: @QHarr Thank you, it is exactly what I needed.