# When is the VBA CVar function actually useful?

Tags: vba, language-lawyer

VBA implicitly converts values to `Variant` as needed, so what would be a use case of the [`CVar` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions)? In the [example given in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions#cvar-function-example), the call to `CVar` is obviously redundant.

To be precise, I am looking for a **concrete, minimal VBA code example**, which

- compiles, but
- won't compile (or produce a different output) when (only!) `CVar(...some expression...)` is replaced by `...some expression...`.

I haven't been able to find such an example, but maybe the someone else can.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think about a real life usage for the following, but at least it shows that you *could* need the function:

```
Sub test()
    Dim myInt As Integer
    myInt = 2
    ' The following call will throw a runtime error in testSub
    Call testSub(myInt)   
    ' That's okay
    Call testSub(CVar(myInt))
End Sub

Sub testSub(ByRef p As Variant)
    Debug.Print "P: " & VarType(p)
    p = "ABC"
End Sub
```

Comment: A good one, I expected it to raise a compile time byref mismatch which it does not. But this kind of problems are usually [worked around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10262247/11683) with `Call testSub((myInt))`.

Comment: In your example `myInt` is also passed as `Variant`, but [with `VT_BYREF`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31637346/11683). The `()` remove that flag. It's an interesting subject with interesting results, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/52686198/11683.

Comment: @GSerg: Just for curiosity: Do you know any way to read the VT-Flags within VBA?

Comment: Yes, read the first two bytes starting at `VarPtr(that_variable)`. An example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43554246/11683

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that qualifies, but the only thing I can think of is the interaction with `As Any` in `Declare`.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
  (Destination As Any, source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

Sub Test()
  Dim source As Long, dest As Long

  source = 42

  CopyMemory dest, CVar(source), 4
  MsgBox dest

  CopyMemory dest, source, 4
  MsgBox dest
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice one! I thought about overloading, but rejected the idea, since VBA itself does not support it, and completely forgot about overload *consuming* with `As Any`.