# How do I simplify/combine these two methods for finding the smallest and largest int in an array?

Tags: java, refactoring

I've written two methods to find the smallest and largest int in an array, but they're nearly identical, so I feel like there should be some way to simplify this, perhaps as one method?

```
private int findMin(){
    int min = arr[0];
    for(int num : arr){
        if(num<min) {
            min = num;
        }
    }
    return min;
}

private int findMax(){
    int max = arr[0];
    for(int num : arr){
        if(num>max){
            max = num;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

I'm not sure how to approach this sort of issue, so I'd love to see your responses!

While [this question on how to pass arithmetic operators to a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902458/is-it-possible-to-pass-arithmetic-operators-to-a-method-in-java) and [this question on how to get both min and max value of Java 8 stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816264/concise-way-to-get-both-min-and-max-value-of-java-8-stream) answer the literal programming problem, my question is on a more fundamental level about to how to approach the problem of methods doing similar things, and ways to compare arrays in general. The answers to this post have been significantly more helpful to me than the answers to those questions.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816264/concise-way-to-get-both-min-and-max-value-of-java-8-stream

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Yay295 and Joe, they're interesting, but the answers to those aren't really what I was looking for. I've edited my post with an explanation.

Comment: Considering that each method is only a few lines of code, may I suggest that creating a simple combined method that invariably takes a parameter isn't particularly worth the (albeit slight) readability hit?
Should you insist, @russianroadman's answer does a good job of creating a combined method and having the specific min and max methods call it. Best of both worlds!

Comment: If you need to trim lines or it will run faster, sure, but otherwise there's really no reason to combine similar methods. They act similar, but they return utterly different things.

Comment: What if the array's empty?

Answer (score 23):

You can implement just one, say `findMax`, and pass it a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that indicates how comparisons should be done:

```
private int findMax(Comparator<Integer> comparator) {
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int num : arr) {
        if (comparator.compare(num, max) > 0) {
            max = num;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Pass `Comparator.naturalOrder()` for the natural ordering of integers, so you get the maximum.

Pass `Comparator.reverseOrder()` for the reverse ordering, so you get the minimum.

Comment: Interesting! I don't quite understand how comparators work yet, but it's going on my list of things to work on haha. I appreciate getting an answer that uses stuff I didnt even know existed.

Comment: As the name suggests, a `Comparator` is a "thing that compares". You can ask it to compare two things by calling its `compare` method, which returns -1 if the first is less than the second, 0 if they are equal, 1 if the first is greater than the second. You could implement your own `Comparator`, but the interface comes with several convenience methods that create commonly used instances like the ones I mentioned above.

Comment: It might be more readable to also provide a `findMin` method that just does `return findMax(comparator.reversed());`, and possibly overload both to default to the `naturalOrder()` comparator.

Answer (score 16):

Your methods are already available in `IntStream` that also deals with empty arrays (indeterminate extremes).

```
private OptionalInt findMin() {
    return IntStream.of(arr).min();
}

private OptionalInt findMax() {
    return IntStream.of(arr).max();
}
```

And like your choice of throwing exceptions:

```
private int findMin() {
    return IntStream.of(arr).min().get();
}

private int findMax() {
    return IntStream.of(arr).max().get();
}
```

Or as method reference:

```
Function<IntStream, OptionalInt> extreme = IntStream::max;
```

Also consider the parallel feature:

```
IntStream.of(arr).parallel().min();
```

---

@Yay295 reminded us of [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html):

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = new IntSummaryStatistics();
IntStream.of(arr).stream()
    .forEach(stats); // stats is an int consumer too.
```

or when doing more

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = IntStream.of(arr)
    .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(IntSummaryStatistics::new,
                    IntSummaryStatistics::accept, 
                    IntSummaryStatistics::combine);
```

and then several numbers can be asked:

```
int min = stats.getMin();
int max = stats.getMax();
int avg = stats.getAverage();
int sum = stats.getSum();
```

---

#### Feedback of @draspa44

> You can end any IntStream, LongStream or DoubleStream simply with .summaryStatistics(). I think this is easier to read than mutating stats or using accept and combine

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = IntStream.of(arr)
    .summaryStatistics();
```

Comment: There's also `Int`, `Long`, and `Double` `SummaryStatistics`. These stream collectors provide min, max, average, count, and sum.

Comment: @Yay295 [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) does collect more, but is in fact even more appropriate as an answer because it combines min and max. Something for an answer!

Comment: Nice catch. It outruns my answer - I was not even aware of that class.

Comment: Warning: don't use `parallel()` unless you can prove with data that your code is too slow without it. It uses a global thread pool that cannot be easily changed (which could cause other code using this pool to take longer to run or to not run at all), and usually the normal stream is faster because the threads that `parallel()` uses have an overhead that, for small to medium-sized streams, just makes things slower.

Comment: @jbduncan true, `parallel` is the SUV of Streams.

Comment: You can end any `IntStream`, `LongStream` or `DoubleStream` simply with `.summaryStatistics()`. I think this is easier to read than mutating `stats` or using `accept` and `combine`.

Comment: @drspa44 that of course is **the** suitable solution. I have added it to the answer, but it would have been better if you would have added it. Unfortunately many highly up-voted answers already exist.

Answer (score 16):

I would not recommend combine two responsibilities into one method

Instead, I would make two methods (max and min) that share same lines of code through a third method.

```
public int min(int[] array){
    return most(array, (a, b) -> a < b)
}

public int max(int[] array){
    return most(array, (a, b) -> a > b)
}

private int most(int[] array, Fuction2 compare){
    int most = array[0];
    for (int num : array) {
        if (compare(num, most)) {
            most = num;
        }
    }
    return most;
}
```

This way you can easily change logic for one method, without changing another
Also, it is easier to use and more readable, than using one method with parameter like "max=true"

Comment: Best of both worlds here!

Comment: That would be my approach as well. Make the user interface as simple, clear, fool-proof and unambiguous as possible; hide complexity and genericity in the implementation. (You can *still* have an advanced API that allows power users access to generic functions though so that they don't get dumbed down and frustrated!)

Comment: Your `Function2` should be `java.util.BiPredicate<Integer, Integer>`

Answer (score 8):

If the number of int's is big and you most of the time need both min and max values, it probably makes sense to go through the list only once and evaluate both min and max at the same time.

Then there is just the question how to communicate two numbers when a function can only have one return value. So we create a special result class for this.

```
class MinMaxResult {
    public int min = 0;
    public int max = 0;
}

MinMaxResult findMinMax() {
    MinMaxResult result = new MinMaxResult();
    result.min = arr[0];
    result.max = arr[0];

    for (int num: arr) {
        if (num < result.min) {
            result.min = num;
        } else if (num > result.max) {
            result.max = num;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Even better, assuming this array only gets populated once, would be to maintain a min and max when adding the numbers to the array in the first place.  Then there's no loop needed to get the values since you've already got them.  A little harder if you're frequently modifying/removing elements.  If that were the case, I'd use some kind of min/max heap structure instead of a flat array if performance is an issue.

Comment: I like that idea, although it would only work while values are added. Removing the one representing the max/min would invalidate the result. But only then a re-scan might be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can also call the class methods `Math.min` and `Math.max` as follows and return the results in a `record`.  Records are immutable classes and were introduced in Java 14.

```
record MinMax(int min, int max) {
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
  

    int[] v = { 1, 1, 20, 3, 3, 10 };

    MinMax result = findMinMax(v);
    System.out.println(result);
    // or
    System.out.println(result.min + ", "+ result.max);
}
```

prints

```
MinMax[min=1, max=20]
1, 20
```

Just iterate over the array and apply the methods to each value and the current value of min or max.

```
public static MinMax findMinMax(int[] values) {
    int max = values[0];
    int min = max;
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        max = Math.max(max, values[i]);
        min = Math.min(min, values[i]);
    }
    return new MinMax(min, max);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is really only one difference, you can pass a boolean to determine which value (min or max) you want.
Something like this:

```
private int findExtreme(boolean findMin) {
    int solution = arr[0];
        for(int num : arr){
            if (findMin){
                if(num<min){
                    solution = num;
                }
            } else {
                if(num>max){
                    solution = num;
                }
            }
        }
    return solution;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I imagine I'll be using comments to make sure i don't mix up wether findMinOrMax(true) gets me min or max haha.

Comment: Possible, but bad for readability. From the call `findMinOrMax(false)` it's impossible to tell what the boolean argument means. An `enum` would be better.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating @Thomas, I hadn't heard of enums before reading through all the responses here, they seem like a very useful tool for making code significantly more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in a boolean that is true to find the minimum or false to find the maximum. The trick is to compare the result of `(num < best)`, which is either true or false, to the boolean argument.

- If `isMinimum` is true then when `(num < best)` is true we have a new minimum.
- If `isMinimum` is false then when `(num < best)` is false we have a new maximum (or a tie for maximum).

```
private int findExtreme(bool isMinimum) {
    int best = arr[0];
    for (int num: arr) {
        if ((num < best) == isMinimum) {
            best = num;
        }
    }
    return best;
}
```

Even better would be to use an enum. Boolean arguments can be hard to decipher just seeing a bare `true` or `false` in a function call. That would look like:

```
public enum Extreme {
    MINIMUM,
    MAXIMUM
}

private int find(Extreme extreme) {
    int best = arr[0];
    for (int num: arr) {
        if ((num < best) == (extreme == Extreme.MINIMUM)) {
            best = num;
        }
    }
    return best;
}
```

Comment: Possible, but bad for readability. From the call `findExtreme(false)` it's impossible to tell what the boolean argument means. An `enum` would be better.

Comment: Right you are. I've added an enum.